# Get a list of directories which complies with a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, subdirectory, directory-structure

I am writing a Python script that list the directories in a directory. The task seems simple.

However, in my case I would like to do something a bit more complicated. Say I have the following structure

```
----folder1----conditionfolder----conditionfile
  |
  |---folder2----conditionfolder
  |
  |---folder3
```

So far the script just lists the directories:

- folder1
- folder2
- folder3

However I want the script to only lists *the directories that complies with a condition*

For example if I want to list the directories that have a subdirectory named "conditionfolder" I will get

- folder1
- folder2

on the other hand if I want to list the directories that have a subdirectory named "conditionfolder" and inside this there is a file named "conditionfile" I will have

- folder1

How can I do this in python?

EDIT:

Following @Susmit Agrawal answer I did this:

```
thelist=list(glob.glob('./*/conditionfolder/conditionfile'))
print(thelist)
```

So now I have a list of the form:

```
['.\\folder1\\conditionfolder\\conditionfile']
```

which is great. However ideally I would like to have this

```
['folder1']
```

meaning only a list of the folders.
I'll guess I can operate on the original list to generate the other one by splitting

Answer (score 1):

If the conditions can be described on the command line as a regex, the simplest way would be to use `glob`:

```
import glob

for path in glob.glob('./*/conditionfolder'):
    # extract required directory name from *path*
```

`'./*/conditionfolder'` can be replaced with any regex available on the command line.

Comment: A glob pattern should not be described as a regex.

Comment: @alani care to elaborate on this?

Comment: @KansaiRobot, you can read about glob here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage os.walk and traverse through the directory structure and print based on condition.

```py
import os

path_to_consider = r'c:\dev\testFolder'
for root,directory,file in os.walk(path_to_consider,topdown=True):
    for d in directory:
           if d == 'conditionfolder':
               print(f"The folder containing conditionFolder is {root}")
    for f in file:
         if f == 'conditionfile.txt':
             print(f"The folder containing conditionFile is {root}")
```